# Excel formula to find 2d lookup

Tags: excel

Could you please help me achieve the result below?

[image]

Base data (Column M to Column O) is the values from where marks should be picked and column D to column I is where the marks should be displayed.

I have used the formula, but it is also showing the marks for Ramesh in History, civics and Social studies, which he has not appeared (as per the base data- column M to column O).

Please help in fixing this error and also let me know if there is any other better way of writing the formula.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMIFS($O$2:$O$16,$M$2:$M$16,$C3,$N$2:$N$16,D$2)
```